# Angular 2 form Change event with a parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Below is the HTML for adding a file as form data. I would like to remove the Add button and pass the value  (ticket.id) during the change $event which will trigger the component to write the file.

Can this be done?

```
<tr *ngFor='let ticket of tickets'>
  <td>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input 
           type="file" 
           class="custom-file-input" 
           id="avatar" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #avatar>
      </div>
      <button 
           type="button" 
           (click)="onSubmit(ticket.id)" 
           [disabled]="form.invalid || loading" 
           class="btn btn-success">
           Add File<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw" *ngIf="loading"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can send number of parameters to your angular events..

Comment: just change onfileChange function to onFileChange($event, ticket.id) in html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, you should be able to pass the `ticket.id` as the second argument to the `change` event like this:

```
<tr *ngFor='let ticket of tickets'>
  <td>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input 
           type="file" 
           class="custom-file-input" 
           id="avatar" 
           (change)="onFileChange($event, ticket.id)" 
           #avatar>
      </div>
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
```